# What chord is this from Hungarian Rhapsody No.2 "G - Db - F"?

Tags: chords

This is an except from Hungarian Rhapsody No.2 by Liszt from John Thompson's Grade 3:

[image]

What is the name of the chord (G,Db,F) and its harmonic function in the bass clef of the second bar?

EDIT:

More context:
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify why you're asking?  (Why does it need to have a name?)

Comment: Can you give a larger example. Knowing how the chord resolves will help explain it's function.

Comment: @MatthewRead Asking for the name and/or function of a sonority would seem to me to be a valid, answerable "theory" question.  "I'm curious" would seem sufficient justification for asking.

Comment: @Andrew Not really, we don't want one question for every conceivable set of notes. A better question would be about how to identify chords, so the poster actually learns something useful.

Comment: @MatthewRead [To meta we go...](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/354/questions-in-the-form-of-what-chord-is-this)

Comment: I like adding musical analysis to the pieces I play, I guess this fall under curiosity also..

Comment: I too like to analyze and add chords, as this helps me read and to some extent interpret the music.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a **Gm7(b5)**.
Note that the Bb of the right hand/melody is also part of the chord - there's no need to double it in the left hand.

This chord might be the IIm7b5 of a IIm7b5-V7-Im cadence in Fm, where the Gm7(b5) would lead you to a C or C7 and after that an Fm, all acting as a tonicization of Fm (from the original tonic which I presume is Cm). I.e. it's function would then be **IIm7b5/IVm**.
But it would be good to see the following bars to make a better judgement of it's function.

EDIT:
After seeing the following bars I totally agree with NReilingh's great comments. The tonic at the time is C (in some frygian mode) and the Gm7(b5) chord function could be described as **Vm7(b5)**.

Comment: You're overthinking it, I believe. This chord has dominant function in the key of C--there's just some mode mixture going on between the key signature of C minor and the tonic chord of C major.

Comment: ... that is to say, I'd call this chord a Vø7.

Comment: Phrygian! Ulf, it's spelled phrygian.